# Convert ZIO Task to IO

Tags: zio

I have the next code:

```
import zio._

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class AppError(description: String) extends Throwable
// legacy-code imitation
def method(x: Int): Task[Boolean] = {
  Task.fromFuture { implicit ec => Future.successful(x == 0) }
}

def handler(input: Int): IO[AppError, Int] = {
  for {
    result <- method(input)
    _ <- IO.fail(AppError("app error")).when(result)
  } yield input
}
```

but this code does not compile, because compiler says result type is:

`ZIO[Any, Throwable, Int]`

How to convert from Task (where I call `method`) to IO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to decide what you want to do with `Throwable` errors which are not `AppError`.

If you decide you want to map them to an `AppError` you can do:

```
method(input).mapError {
  case ae: AppError => ae
  case other =>        AppError(other.getMessage)
}
```

If you want to refine those errors and only keep the ones that are `AppError` then you can use one of the `refine*` family of operators, which will keep errors that match the predicate and terminate the fiber otherwise.

```
method(input).refineToOrDie[AppError] // IO[AppError, Boolean]
// Or
method(input).refineOrDie { case ae: AppError => ae } // IO[AppError, Boolean]
```

Or if you want to assume that all errors from `method` are considered "Fiber terminating", then you can use `.orDie` to absorb the error and kill the fiber:

```
method(input).orDie // UIO[Boolean]
```

Or if you want to recover from the error and handle it a different way then you could use the `catch*` family

```
method(input).catchAll(_ => UIO.succeed(false)) // UIO[Boolean]
```

Finally if you wanted to have the result mapped into an `Either` you could use `.either`, which will lift the error out of the error channel and map it into `Either[E, A]`

```
method(input).either // UIO[Either[Throwable, Boolean]]
```

There is a great cheat sheet (though admittedly a bit out of date) [here](https://github.com/ghostdogpr/zio-cheatsheet) as well