# Scala, ZIO - how to convert EitherT to ZIO?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, zio

I have a simple method signature with returning type as `EitherT`:

```
def run(someEither: Either[SomeException, Statement], id: String): EitherT[Future, EncodingException, ResultSet]
```

But higher level method has a signature:

```
def someMethod(...) : zio.IO[SomeException, SomeResult]
```

I call `run` method inside `someMethod` like this:

```
run(someEither, data.getOrElse("empty")).bimap(
      { e: SomeException => IO.fail(e) },
      _ => IO.succeed(entity)
    )
```

But I got compilation error about `Type mismatch` - required: `IO`, found: `EitherT`.
How it is possible to convert `EitherT` into `zio.IO`?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your data looks like and how you want to handle failed futures, but here's a few options for if you don't care to handle specific kinds of Throwables from the Future:

```
// EitherT[Future, E, A] to IO[E, A]
val io: IO[E, A] =
  ZIO.fromFuture(eitherT.value)
    .orDie
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)

// EitherT[Future, Throwable, A] to Task[A]
val task: Task[A] =
  ZIO
    .fromFuture(_ => et.value)
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)

// EitherT[Future, Throwable, A] to UIO[A]
val task: UIO[A] =
  ZIO
    .fromFuture(_ => et.value)
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)
    .orDie
```

## Longer explanation

First off, there isn't a built-in for converting from `EitherT`, so you'll need to use the underlying `Future`, from which you can very quickly get to a ZIO `Task`:

```
val eitherT: EitherT[Future, A, B] = ???
val underlying: Future[Either[A, B]] = eitherT.value

// Note that this is equivalent to IO[Throwable, Either[...]]
val zioTask: Task[Either[MyError, MyResult]] = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => underlying)

// Or all at once:
val zioTask = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => eitherT.value)
```

I had a similar need as the OP, but in my case the Left is not an exception but rather my own `MyError` instead:

```
val underlying: Future[Either[MyError, MyResult]]
```

If you're in a similar boat, then you need to make a decision about what to do with any exceptions that might be in a possible failed future. One possible option is to...

### Ignore them and let the fiber die if they happen

If the exception in the future represents a defect in the code, then often there is no other choice than to let the fiber die as it cannot proceed further. A fiber killed with `orDie` will have a `Throwable` representing the cause, but you have the option – which I recommend – to use your own exception that details how and why the failure occurred via `orDieWith`.

```
val uio: UIO[Either[MyError, MyResult]] = task.orDie

// Or

case class ExplanatoryException(cause: Throwable)
  extends RuntimeException(
    "A failure was encountered when we used XYZ-lib/made service call to FooBar/etc",
    cause
  )
val uio: UIO[Either[MyError, MyResult]] = task.orDieWith(ExplanatoryException)

// Then finally

val fullyConverted: IO[MyError, MyResult] = uio.flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)
```

Now from here you have a clean `IO` to work with!

### Extension methods!

If you're doing this a lot you can add an extension method to `EitherT` to do the conversion for you:

```
implicit class EitherTOps[A, B](et: EitherT[Future, A, B]) {
  def toIO: IO[A, B] = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => et.value)
    .orDie
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)

  def toIOWith(f: Throwable => Throwable): IO[A, B] = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => et.value)
    .orDieWith(f)
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)
}
```

### And beyond!

If you're able to constrain `A <: Throwable` then it makes it pretty easy to write some convenient `toTask` extension methods for EitherT, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

If you know *a priori* what kind of `Throwable` you may get from the Future and you want to actually handle it gracefully, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62863590/446554) which covers all the ways to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like:

```scala
import zio._
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.Future

type ResultSet = ???

val eitherT: EitherT[Future, Exception, ResultSet] = ???
val result: IO[Throwable, ResultSet] = ZIO.fromFuture(_ => eitherT.value).flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)
```

Comment: for some reasons code didn't compile until I changed it to `.flatMap(r => ZIO.fromEither(r))` in a for comprehension